# Django objects and openpyxl cells. How to set cell value like a value of django object field?

Tags: python, django, openpyxl

I have to write a block of code which generates an xlsx report from Django dataset( few models). Frame of the report have more difficult structure than usual x rows y columns (some cells was united). It should look like that:

[image]

So I wrote view function:

```
from cut.models import *
from django.http import HttpResponse
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Protection, Font

def get_report(request):
    
    rent_test = Renters.objects.all

    response = HttpResponse(
        content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    )
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=FORM_1-IL.xlsx'.format()
    workbook = Workbook()

    worksheet = workbook.active
    worksheet.title = 'A_REPORT'
    
    worksheet.merge_cells('A2:A5')
#...
    worksheet.merge_cells('M4:M5')

    worksheet['A2'].value = 'name of forestry'
#...etc.
    columns = [
    'only_one_column'
    ]
    row_num = 1

    for col_num, column_title in enumerate(columns, 1):
        cell = worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num)
        cell.value = column_title

    
    workbook.save(response)

    return response
```

So it is all understandable and simple.
But how I can use Django fields? I wish to transfer them to relative cell( value of field instead red font "field value"

Comment: Presumably you call a method on the field to get it's value.

Comment: @CharlieClark something like this? ```worksheet['A27'].value = ForestryKeys.objects.get(pk=7)```

Comment: If I use it, django throws this ```Cannot convert <ForestryKeys: ForestryKeys object (7)> to Excel

Comment: You should update your code and include the full exception, which in this case is coming from openpyxl. I'm not familiar with Django but presumably you need to call a method on whatever `ForestryKeys.objects.get(pk=7)` returns.